# Recipe for target 'graphite-clast-to-gimple.o' failed when I compile GCC Cross-Compiler

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I would like to create a GCC cross-compiler and I follow the instruction here  [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler) But the problem is each time when I make gcc will have same error blow.

> ../../gcc-4.8.2/gcc/graphite-clast-to-gimple.c:897:24: error: ‘isl_lp_ok’
>
> was not declared in this scope
>
> assert (lp_result == isl_lp_ok);
>                         ^
>   ../../gcc-4.8.2/gcc/graphite-clast-to-gimple.c:898:34: error:
>
> ‘isl_int_get_gmp’ was not declared in this scope
>
> isl_int_get_gmp (isl_value, low);                                  ^
>
> ../../gcc-4.8.2/gcc/graphite-clast-to-gimple.c:900:57: error: ‘isl_set_max’
>
> was not declared in this scope
>
> lp_result = isl_set_max (domain, dimension, &isl_value);
>                                                            ^
>   ../../gcc-4.8.2/gcc/graphite-clast-to-gimple.c:904:27: error:
>
> ‘isl_int_clear’ was not declared in this scope
>
> isl_int_clear (isl_value);                           ^
>
> Makefile:1058: recipe for target 'graphite-clast-to-gimple.o' failed
>
> make[1]: *** [graphite-clast-to-gimple.o] Error 1
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mike/src/build-gcc/gcc'
>
> Makefile:3927: recipe for target 'all-gcc' failed
>
> make: *** [all-gcc] Error 2

At first,I think it may caused by the version problem because the gcc on my openSUSE is 4.8.3,but nothing changed after I use version 4.8.2.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

There's a problem with the latest version (0.14?) of the ISL library - the API is not compatible with gcc as of 4.9.2. As for building CLooG, the ISL-0.12.1 version included with 0.18.2 doesn't get configured properly. So you need to build and install your own libraries, and then use those when configuring gcc.

1/. [isl-0.12.2](http://isl.gforge.inria.fr)

```
> ./configure --prefix=$CROSSDIR --with-gmp-prefix=$GMPDIR
> make install # and rehash, etc.
```

where `CROSSDIR` is where you're installing your cross compiler toolchain, and `GMPDIR` is the root directory containing `lib` and `include` directories for GMP. Unfortunately, this means you will need to build GMP, MPFR, and MPC separately and install, or install them from a package system first. But you might not need this (**see below**).

2/. [cloog-0.18.2](http://bastoul.net/cloog/pages/download/)

```
> ./configure --prefix=$CROSSDIR --with-isl-prefix=$CROSSDIR \
--with-gmp-prefix=$GMPDIR
```

There's a ridiculous issue where the Makefile has 'cmake' strings lying about. The solution (from clfs.org) :

```
> sed '/cmake/d' Makefile > Makefile.new
> mv Makefile.new Makefile
> make install # and rehash, etc.
```

When configuring gcc, use: `--with-isl=$CROSSDIR --with-cloog=$CROSSDIR`, and you will need options for: `--with-gmp`, `--with-mpfr`, `--with-mpc`

---

Alternatively - following the instructions you're using, it may be sufficient to move isl-0.12.2 & cloog-0.18.2 to the isl and cloog subtrees in the gcc source tree. After the configure, go into the cloog build subdirectory and edit the Makefile as above. I haven't tried this. I build and install the packages separately under CROSSDIR for other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux, you could probably get the development packages for your system. I know the commands for a Debian-based system such as Ubuntu and its variants.

```
sudo apt-get install libisl-dev
sudo apt-get install libcloog-isl-dev
```

After that, delete the isl and cloog directories in your gcc folder, then try to continue from:

```
make all-gcc
```

If you don't have a Debian-based system, some hunting around in Google Forest should help.

Comment: Or even simpler: `aptitude build-dep gcc`